# HTML drop down bar does not work on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS and JavaScript at the moment and on my HTML I have made a dropdown bar and it works on Chrome and firefox but not Internet Explorer. I need the drop down bar to work on internet explorer.

This is my **CSS** code:

```
<body bgcolor='#52CC7A'>
        <style type="text/css">
    * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    body { padding: 5px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    ul { list-style: none; z-index: 999 }
    ul li { float: left; padding-right: 1px; position: relative; }
    ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; height: 50px; text-align: center; background: #69C; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }
    ul a:hover { background: #09C; }
    li > ul { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100%; }
    li:hover > ul { display: block; }
    li > ul li { padding: 0; padding-top: 1px; }
    li > ul li > ul { left: 100%; top: 0; padding-left: 1px; }
    li > ul li > ul li { width: 100px; }
    li:hover > a { background: #09C; }
</style>
```

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Players</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
```

There is a lot more to it but that is it simplified.

Does anyone know how to change any code or change something to make this work on Internet  Explorer? Thanks :)

Comment: probably due to malformed html?

Comment: You'll need to explain why you think it's not working and post more of your HTML code

Comment: it works for me in IE8+...need evidence?

Comment: reproduce it in fiddle

Comment: well no i have been told its not the html code it is in the css code so i need to find a different code to do it

Comment: hey everyone i found out the problem you need <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest showing more code and giving the version of IE.

Possibly you are lacking a `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your document which IE requires for the :hover and > selectors to [work](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: well yes thats what i thought but i cant seem to find any other codes

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in IE (tested in 8 and 11). I corrected your HTML to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Players</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments it works for me perfectly in IE8+

I haven't gone through all the css but in IE7 it seems that `display:table-cell` is playing up...it is known to have issues in IE7. If you change it to display `inline-block` and add a line height of `50px` so that the text is nicely aligned vertically you should be fine. So, this is all I'd change...

```
ul a 
{ 
    display: inline-block;  /* <-- change to inline-block  */
    line-height:50px; /* <-- align text vertically  */
    *display:inline; /* <-- IE7 hack  */
     zoom:1; /* <-- IE7 hack */
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: #69C; 
    color: #FFF; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

notice that I added a hack for IE7 because it does NOT support `inline-block`

Finally, this is how it looks...

[image]